# Initializing Javascript Object at zero?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to initialize a object with zero the way you can initialize a hash in ruby with 0 value?

Hash.new(0)...Object.create(0)?

I am trying to itterate thru an array and add each element as a key and increment the values.

Answer (score 4):

No.

But you can do things like

```
tab[key] = (tab[key] || 0) + 1;
```

Having a default value would be slightly nicer but it wouldn't work when the default needs to be an expression to be evaluated only if needed.

With this pattern instead you can easily do things like

```
return cache[key] || (cache[key] = new Machine(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always create an `Array` with a default value using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arrSize = 10;
var arr = Array.apply(null, new Array(arrSize)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);
console.log(arr); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're trying to create an empty object you can just:

```
var obj = {};
```

Here's some stuff that wasn't asked for to deter downvotes

```
var obj = {};
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet,', 
 'consectetur', 'adipisicing', 'elit.', 'Enim', 
 'nam', 'aperiam,', 'doloribus', 'dolor', 'ullam', 
 'corrupti', 'aliquid', 'Magni', 'consequuntur', 
 'velit', 'consectetur', 'autem', 'sit', 'sint',
 'temporibus', 'inventore'].forEach(function(a, i) {
    obj[a] = i;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

Comment: I think you missed the location of the questionmark.

Comment: That was either to encourage improving/ deleting the answer. Now I'll take it back ;)

Comment: Initializing with zero (original question) is not the same as creating an empty object. Please revisit your answer.